# Angular Material Expansion Panel: No Animation in Ionic iOS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-material, expandable, collapsable

Trying to use [Angular Material Expansion Panel](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview) for an accordion/collapsable list inside an Ionic app.

When I run it in the browser using `ionic serve`, I get smooth animations.
[image]

When I run in in the iOS simulator/iPhone 7, the animation is gone.
[image]

**Why doesn't it work on iOS?**

Answer (score 0):

Some Material components depend on the Angular animations module in order to be able to do more advanced transitions. If you want these animations to work in your app, you have to install the @angular/animations module and include the BrowserAnimationsModule in your app.

Note: @angular/animations uses the WebAnimation API that isn't supported by all browsers yet. If you want to support Material component animations in these browsers, you'll have to include a polyfill.

source : [Angular getting started guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)